# How to delete a file that's no longer in the directory?

Tags: windows-8.1, file-management

So I downloaded a music file but I was surprised when I saw it had no extension and it was 0kB. I decided to delete it but then I got that terrible error message saying that the file is no longer in the folder I see it is in!!!

I don't think my hardware is so weak that it can't refresh my Explorer Window...

So what I first had in mind was to use admin rights cmd to delete the file as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRSKHv20Usc (yes, I had that problem before, on Windows 7 and that solved it for me).

But on Windows 8.1 I can't see short filenames for ANY file, not just the corrupt one. (Is that a bug or is it supposed to be so? My corrupt file has a dot in its name -- a disallowed character, I believe?)

What can I do to delete this file?

I tried creating and then deleting it, a new version of the same file was created again what is wrong with that?

Comment: You should be able to use a [Linux Live environment](http://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character) of your choice to access the drive then delete it.  When you attempt to delete the file.  What error message do you get exactly? Additional [reading](http://superuser.com/questions/805882/how-to-delete-a-file-with-a-bad-file-name?rq=1)

Comment: Did you restart explorer? Refresh the folder using F5?

Comment: Of course dot is allowed; *every* file has one on windows.  Think `*.exe`, `*.doc`, etc.

Comment: Yes but dot is not an extension, anyway yes again, I did restart the explorer and I did try F5.

Comment: "I tried creating and then deleting it, a new version of the same file was created again" Can you explain this better?  You created a new fie with the same name (in the same folder) as the file you can't delete, then deleted it, and then a new file of the same name (re)appeared? Have you run a disk check yet?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Are you talking about `chkdsk` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about (or right click the drive -> properties tools -> error-checking)

Comment: It said that no errors were found but the file remains.

Comment: Oh yes, this has worked for me @Moab. Thanks for the solution!